# Embed javascript file in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a designer in html. I am drawing widgets on canvas and then on save button click canvas is downloaded as html page on user PC. But problem is that widgets that i am using need two JavaScript files to be linked. i.e. I have to paste those two JavaScript file in the directory of downloaded html page. Otherwise it didn't work. 
So is there a way to embed these files in my saved file. I don't want user to copy paste .js files along with html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy and paste these JavaScript files' content in a script block and remove their references. For example, change:

```
<script src="external.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script>
  // copy and paste the content of external.js here
</script>
```

Do this to all the JavaScript dependencies.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Use Firebug or an equivalent debugger to see where it broke.

Comment: It worked... There was problem with the order of pasted code. I was pasting it at the end. The i pasted at top and it worked

Comment: I'm happy to have helped out. An answer acceptance or a up-vote is appreciated.