# Linking HTML and JS files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

If previously asked, then sorry , i was not able to locate it.

So here is a html file :index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ToDoList</title>
    <script> src="AddItem.js" </script>
    <script> src="RemoveItem.js" </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Write to Add to List </h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="inpu">
    <input type="button" onclick="/AddItem.js/add()" value="submit">
    <div>
        <ul id="list">

        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the JavaSCript file: AddItem.js

```
var n=0;
function add() {
    if(n==0)
    {
        var ul = document.getElementById("list");
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Four"));
        li.setAttribute("id", "element4"); // added line
        ul.appendChild(li);
        alert(li.id);
    }
}
```

So i am getting errors, i am unable to link the function add() to the button in my html file, i tried writing only the function name, but still doesn't work.
I also heard of something "window.onload" , but dont know how that will help.

yes i tried using AddItem.js as a file name, but i get error :SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag a

-A JS newbie here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed javascript file in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189430/embed-javascript-file-in-html)

Comment: It is '<script src="RemoveItem.js" />'

Comment: Thanks @John3136 , but i dont want to include script in my html file, so please remove the duplicate

Comment: @Dijkgraaf  yes i tried that , it gives an error  SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag a

Comment: Add these before `</body>` ending tag `<script src="AddItem.js"></script>` and `<script src="RemoveItem.js"></script>` if you want to include the js file, simply put your code inside `<script> <!-- code here --> </script>` and remove the `"/AddItem.js/"` from `<input type="button" onclick="/AddItem.js/add()" value="submit">`

Comment: @LohitakshTrehan Did you read the duplicate? It answers your question.

Comment: @John3136  , yes but i would like to maintain the modularity , btw X.Liu already answered it and helped me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
<script> src="AddItem.js" </script>
<script> src="RemoveItem.js" </script>
```

to

```
<script src="AddItem.js"></script>
<script src="RemoveItem.js"></script>
```

And change

```
<input type="button" onclick="/AddItem.js/add()" value="submit">
```

to

```
<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="submit">
```

Comment: Thanks, you really helped a newbie :)

Answer (score 1):

Add these before ending `</body>` tag to make sure that your HTML loads first before the JS files.

`<script src="AddItem.js"></script>` and

`<script src="RemoveItem.js"></script>`

if you don't want to include the js file, simply put your code inside

`<script> <!-- code here --> </script>`

or

```
<script>
    var n=0;
    function add() {
        if(n==0)
        {
            var ul = document.getElementById("list");
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Four"));
            li.setAttribute("id", "element4"); // added line
            ul.appendChild(li);
            alert(li.id);
        }
    }
</script>
```

and remove the `/AddItem.js/` from

`<input type="button" onclick="/AddItem.js/add()" value="submit">`

so that it would look like this:

`<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="submit">`

Answer (score 0):

Add the `scr=""` in the tag

```
<script src="AddItem.js"></script>
```